# Basic Inquiry about Java Scanner

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to get Java's scanner to keep accepting input until the user types some variation of "end," like, "END", "eNd", "eND", etc.

However, due to my limited experience with Scanner, I can't think of code that would work for all variations of "end". Here's what I have so far:

```
private static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
String textBody = "";

while(!userInput.hasNext("end") && !userInput.hasNext("END"))
{
textBody +=  userInput.nextLine() + "\n";
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: It'd probably be more reasonable to read in lines until the toLowerCase is "end".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to terminate the loop when the user enters a line that consists of "end" (in some variation of capitals, but not terminate when the user enters "end of the road", then try something like this:

```
private static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line = userInput.nextLine();
while(!line.equalsIgnoreCase("end"))
{
    sb.append(line).append('\n');
    line = userInput.nextLine();
}

String textBody = sb.toString();
```

(You could write this as a `for` loop equally well.)

Comment: Be aware that this only works if the string "end" is the only text in the line, without white spaces before or after it.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez - Good point. The problem with white space (if it's a problem for OP) could be fixed by using `!line.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("end")`.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the string returned by `Scanner.nextLine` to lower case with `String.toLowerCase` and compare it to `"end"`.

Comment: No need to use `new String("end")`. Just compare it to `"end"`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, using regular expressions:

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
Pattern end = Pattern.compile("end", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
String textBody = "";

while(!userInput.hasNext(end)) {
    textBody +=  userInput.nextLine() + "\n";
}
```